# How to code my android app to permanent reside in Developer Options at Running Services

Tags: android

Looking in my Android 9.0 Developer Options at Running Services I see commercial Apps with Running Services permanent residing here. (no notification icons are shown)

How must I code my app (with a service) to join permanent the running services? an example would be great.

Thank you.

[image: Running Services]

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea of android programming or java, but this seems pretty straightforward, as such problems are usually very explicitly described in developer documentations.

Does this one help?
https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service

Comment: why is my comment removed two times, as my comments were in line with the regulations?